# Wifi No Internet

Tags: wireless, internet, realtek

I've been using Ubuntu for a few years now but I'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination, I use it just for Internet browsing.

Recently after a software update, which updated the kernel from 6.2.0.26 to 6.2.0.36, my wireless connection would stop with the error "No Internet" but still connected to my router. Hunted high and low for a solution and basically screwed up the machine trying all the different fixes out there. Gave up and reloaded the entire machine.

So now my starting point is 6.2.0.26 and all is fine, updated again to 6.2.0.37 problem has returned. I'm at a loss.

HP laptop with a Realtek wireless card.

Rebooting fixes the problem as does resetting the network manager but that's a real pain.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated but if you need me to supply you with more technical information please give me the exact command line to run. I can cut and paste into a terminal and give you the results but I'm a real novice with Linux.

Thanks guys, here's the output from the command you gave:
Here's the output from the command you gave, thanks for that:
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8a1d]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be

Does that give any useful information?

Comment: I've the exact same problem. Not always, but from time to time after I login into Kubuntu Desktop, wifi isn't working. When I restart the machine, it starts working. Maybe it's about Realtek not being compatible with Ubuntu somehow. I have also asked this and someone is answering me, follow my post for it. This has been duplicate. By the way, I'm using dual OS, Windows+Kubuntu. Are you also?

Comment: @Stockfish your `Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201` seems unlikely to have the same problem (or same solution) as this Querent's Realtek.

Comment: If your description is accurate, then seems like you have clearly shown a *reversion* (it used to demonstrably work well, now broken). 1) Keep using the -26 kernel. 2) File a bug report (`ubuntu-bug linux`) detailing your exact Realtek chipset (`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`).  Kernel bugs are often hardware-specific, so be as accurate and precise as possible. Clearly list the steps to duplicate. 3) Respond to the bug triager when they ask questions. They probably have different hardware, so cannot experience the bug themself. If they ask you to help test a patch, do it. Help them to help you.

Comment: Type Alt+F2 and type ubuntu-bug <package name>, what would be the <package name> in this instance?